# Get host url from Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a java applet which is hosted on a device's web page.  The applet needs to retrieve data from the device at runtime.  Currently the device is configured to output the required data out port 8080 (so, say, 192.168.1.1:8080).  How would I inform my applet of its host web page's URL so that it would know where to get the data from?

Thanks,  John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Applet#getCodeBase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29). This method returns the URL of the directory which contains this applet.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FromWhere extends Applet {
  public void init() {
    Label label = new Label(getCodeBase().toString());
    add(label);
 }
}
```

Note : NULL is returned if the applet is loaded from the file system since [JDK1.7b25](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Applet#getDocumentBase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase%28%29)